# android notification weekly

Tags: java, android

I try to set up an Android App. This have to notificate me every week Friday at 15.00 / 3.00 pm o'clock. To set up the notification every day at this time was no problem, but even not on the specific day and time.

I hope you find my mistake and can give me some hints. Here my code:

```
private void alarmMethod(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Thanks in regards

Tim

Answer (score 1):

For repeating alarm (setRepeating, setInexactRepeating) you should setup time in the future (if the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately). So if you need alarm at every Friday first of all you shoud calculate next friday:

```
private void alarmMethod() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    // get current time
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();  

    // setup time for alarm
    Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set time-part of alarm
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);    
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.Friday);

    // check if it in the future
    if (currentTime.getTimeInMillis() <  alarmTime.getTimeInMillis()) {
        // nothing to do - time of alarm in the future
    } else {            
        int dayDiffBetweenClosestFriday = (7 + alarmaTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) % 7;

        if (dayDiffBetweenClosestFriday == 0) {
            // Today is Friday, but current time after 3pm, so schedule for the next Friday
            dayDiffBetweenClosestFriday = 7;
        }

        alarmTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayDiffBetweenClosestFriday);
    }

    // calculate interval (7 days) in ms
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
}
```

Also you should automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the device (by default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down):

- Set the **RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED** permission in your application's manifest
- Implement a BroadcastReceiver to receive the broadcast **android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED**
- Add the receiver to your app's manifest file with an intent filter that filters on the **ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED** action

Comment: sir, can you elaborate more about BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED and ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED. If possible may I ask for the codes? thank you

Comment: Here - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services#starting-a-service-at-device-boot is a good tutorial